# Method parameter class extends other Java

Tags: java

I have trouble with creating flexible code. Everything I know is that the parameter extends other class and it needs to be final.

```
public void doSomething(final Food food, int position) {
        final Animal animal = animals.get(position);

        if (animal.getType().equals("Bear") {

            food.color = "red"; // important line
        }
}

class Food {

}

class Salomon extends Food {
   String color;
}
```

The question is how to get access to color if I am sure that when animal type is Bear the food that I send is Salomon ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the parameter extends other class"?  Why do you think it needs to be final?

Comment: Also, you have declared `food` as a `Food`, which doesn't have a `color`.  I'm assuming that your question has to do with how to resolve the compilation errors that you'd get with the code you've posted?

Comment: I know that it doesn't have color, so I am asking how to get color from food. Trust me, it needs to be final, because it's part of Android code.

Comment: `Food` does not have a color, only `Salomon` (salmon?) - `food.color` does not work because it does not inherit it from salmon (but salmon does have this property)

Comment: If you know for a fact that the `Food` object will be an instance of `Salomon`, can't you just cast it as such?

Comment: `((Salomon)food).color = "red"` ?